# How to make a portfolio with LaTeX

Tags: templates, document-classes

I've been surfing the CTAN website but I haven't been lucky.

Does anybody known an appropriate document class in LaTeX to produce a Graphic Designer portfolio? I wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel. Or maybe do you have some better idea to achieve this in an elegant way in LaTeX?

Notice that I don't want to give it a very artistic look, so I would like to go with LaTeX and not any Graphic Design software.

Comment: What exactly would a graphic designer's portfolio look like? Like a CV/Resume with graphics included? If so, start with one of the options like `resume.cls`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Thanks jaybee. I'll try resume.cls. Maybe, another aproximation would be a catalogue. A big image per page with some data associated with it (dimensions, prize, year...). Any idea?

Comment: I would think that a graphic designer in need of a portfolio would want to use graphic designing software.  But if you want to use LaTeX, feel free!  Then add it to your résumé as one of your skills. :-)

Comment: Yes, Matthew. Sure a graphic designer would want to use graphic designing software, but I'm not a ghraphic designer :) I'm just arranging all of my partner work (she's the graphic designer) as a present, and I'm from the computing racional world, so I'll use LaTeX and let her later to change it into a sensorial experience :)

Comment: See David Walden's article in the [Practex journal](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-2/walden/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to create some sort of catalogue, then you could simply use the figure environment with the [p] specifier, and probably a simple custom macro to easily format the captions in a uniform way.

Comment: Think it's a good idea to simply use the figure environment. I'll try as well and later I'll share with you.

Comment: Finally, I have decided to use this solution. What I want is very simple, and using the figure environment is ideal. Nevertheless, using the [p] specifier doesn't produce the figure to appear one per page, instead it put the figure in a special page for floats only. To get the pagebreak, I have to use \clearpage (and not \newpage, because I think the latest first fits the figure and then produces a newline), so my code looks like this for each figure:  `\begin{figure}  \centering  \includegraphics{whateverFileImage}  \caption{whateverCaption}  \end{figure}  \clearpage`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the package `pdfpages`, if your portfolio consists of a bunch of PDFs. You can choose the papersize depending on each PDF. You surely are aware that a `texdoc pdfpages` on a commandline will produce the manual.